# Springboot Microservice is registered with Eureka but cannot hit it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Basic question so just want to ensure I understand it all correctly.

I have created a discovery server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DisocveryServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DisocveryServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
```

and registered microservices with it successfully; If I hit localhost:8761 I can see my discovery service has found the microservices. The microservices run fine if i hit them on their designated port. For example, I have one called creds and if i hit localhost:9000 it returns. However, My understanding is I should now be able to hit localhost:8761/creds and it will show the same output but this isnt working.

Am I misunderstanding? Any suggestions on what I should try?

creds bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: creds
```

creds application.yml
server:
  port: 9000
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

discover application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `@EnableEurekaClient` annotated Spring boot webservice can access your creds webservice by using an injected `RestTemplate` with `http://creds/...`, where `creds` is the `spring.application.name` registered with Eureka.

If you want to access the creds webservice from the outside of your web application, then what you want is a proxy like Zuul http://github.com/Netflix/zuul.

Answer (score 0):

Just registering micro service to Eureka server wont make sure that you can access the microservice under a gateway. Eureka Server is not a gateway server , its just a service registry. You can think Eureka as just one more service that holds information about all the other services in the cluster. It doesnt do anything extra other than getting information to the Clients registered. 
You may need a Gateway service for routing your request under the Eureka Server. Zuul Proxy routes a request coming to it to the under lying microservices using its service id or the URL configured.

Add this dependency in your classpath.

```
dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this config in your properties filezuul:

```
  routes:
    serv1:
      path: /serv1/**
      serviceId: http://localhost:8080/serv1
    serv2:
      path: /serv2/**
      serviceId: serv2
```

This will create a dynamic router that routes your request to appropriate service instances. This also provides a server end load balancer for your services